wlan0 won't establish connection after MAC change UBUNTU Touch
I am trying to change the MAC address of my wlan0 device, I tried with ifconfig wlan0 hw ether. I tried also macchanger, but after I changed it WiFi won't establish a connection. It sees the WiFi networks and prompts for the password, but it won't connect.
if i turn wlan0 in hotspot mode with nmcli dev wifi hotspot and then killall wpa_supplicant something reloads the WPA_SUPPLICANT and WiFi gets working.
is there a way to change MAC on boot time before loading the WPA_SUP.... ???
I apply part from dmesg with connection attempt:
[10678.334102] wlan: [4255:E :WDA]  scan complete - scan_id a065, vdev_id 0
[10678.335161] wlan: [2566:E :SME] Found 9 BSS, statusCode 0
[10678.346879] wlan: [2783:E :HDD] wlan_hdd_cfg80211_set_ie Set UNKNOWN IE 3B
[10678.347884] wlan: [2566:E :SME] Connecting to ssid:Sharky bssid: 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6 rssi: -45 channel: 11 country_code: 00
[10678.348634] wlan: [2566:E :WDA] wma_create_peer: Created peer with peer_addr 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6 vdev_id 0, peer_count - 1
[10678.423676] wlan: [2566:E :WDA] wma_add_sta_req_sta_mode:statype 0 vdevid 0 aid 3 bssid 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6 staIdx 1 status 0
[10678.423836] wlan: 00:03:7f:50:00:02 connected to 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6
[10678.423975] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[10678.424523] 1 log buffers are dropped
[10678.795143] [SSP]      debug_work_func( 447): (60) - Sensor state: 0x4f24f4176, RC: 0, CC: 0 DC: 0 TC: 0
[10678.795209] [SSP] 1 : -18, -19, 4019 (100ms, 0ms)
[10682.381878] [SSP] [M] AR--15,-17,4042,100,-1
[10682.463472] wlan: [4255:E :SYS] sysBbtProcessMessageCore: 192: DEAUTH frame allowed: da: 00:03:7f:50:00:01, sa: 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6, bssid: 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6, DEAUTH count so far: 1

[10682.463671] wlan: [2566:E :PE ] limProcessDeauthFrame: 171: Received Deauth frame for Addr: 00:03:7f:50:00:01 (mlm state=eLIM_MLM_LINK_ESTABLISHED_STATE sme state=12 systemrole=3 RSSI=-51) with reason code 2 [eSIR_MAC_PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID_REASON] from 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6
[10682.463758] wlan: [2566:F :WDA] WDA_TxAbort: vdevid 0 bssid 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6
[10682.464006] wlan: [2566:E :SME] smeProcessCommand: 868: SessionId 0:  Cannot process command(131075) while waiting for key
[10682.464717] wlan: disconnected
[10682.466913] wlan: [2566:E :SME] PMC: failure to send messageeWNI_PMC_ENTER_BMPS_REQ status 1
[10682.466985] wlan: [2566:E :SME] pmcOffloadExitPowersaveState: 3383: Master Sta Ps Disabled
[10682.468881] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[10682.471856] wlan: [5953:E :WDA] regdmn_set_dfs_region: dfs_region: 0
[10682.471952] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[10682.471997] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[10682.472026] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[10682.472093] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472129] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472204] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472239] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472274] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472309] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472372] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472407] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[10682.472792] TXRX: ol_txrx_peer_detach:peer ffffffc08d6c1000 (00:1e:73:58:9e:e6)
[10682.472854] wlan: [2566:E :WDA] wma_remove_peer: Removed peer with addr 00:1e:73:58:9e:e6 vdevid 0 peer_count 0
[10682.478090] TXRX: ol_rx_peer_unmap_handler: Remove the ID 16 reference to peer ffffffc08d6c1000
[10682.478276] TXRX: ol_rx_peer_unmap_handler: Remove the ID 0 reference to peer ffffffc08d6c1000
[10682.478317] TXRX: Deleting peer ffffffc08d6c1000 (00:1e:73:58:9e:e6)


Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  What was Ubuntu Touch is now Lomiri supported by UBports Foundation - refer https://ubports.com/
